# How can I fix the show the value of array with the Binary Search Tree of Comparison?

Tags: java

I got some error to output the java of Binary Search Tree with comparison:

And now I going to search some of the value in the array, did I need to create a method to handle it? For example, I going to find 22 of the comparison. How can I implement this?

The Answer here:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    //  int i = binarySearch(0, new int[]{32,21,13,44});
        int i = binarySearch(0, new int[]{9, 21, 33, 44, 66, 72, 90});
        System.out.println("This program is going to implement the below binary search method!");
        System.out.println("[9, 21, 33, 44, 66, 72, 90]");
        System.out.println("Comparisons: " + i);

    }
```

Comment: In int i = this.binarySearch(0, [4]); did I needed to change the (4 , [32,21,13,44]);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first , you cannot use 'this' before calling binarySearch method because 'main' is a static method.
second , your 'binarySearch' method accept an array of integers, so you have to pass an array to it , and [4] is not.
you have to change [4] by an array , some thing like:

```
int i = binarySearch(0, new int[]{32,21,13,44});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the way of you defined and passed the array value: `[4]` and you have to change it as below:

```
int i = binarySearch(0, new int[] {4});
```